# Failed to compile cuda_ndarray.cu theano on windows 7

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, theano, theano-cuda

Hi I am trying to run theano on gpu.

My configuration is

Windows 7

CUDA toolkit 8.0

Anaconda python 3.5

Visual studio 14.0

```
===============================
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
ERROR (theano.sandbox.cuda): Failed to compile cuda_ndarray.cu: ('nvcc return status', 1, 'for cmd', 'nvcc -shared -O3 -LC:\\Anaconda\\libs --compiler-bindir C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\bin -Xlinker /DEBUG -D HAVE_ROUND -m64 -Xcompiler -DCUDA_NDARRAY_CUH=mc72d035fdf91890f3b36710688069b2e,-DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION,/Zi,/MD -IC:\\Users\\aniketb\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\theano\\sandbox\\cuda -IC:\\Users\\aniketb\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\core\\include -IC:\\Users\\aniketb\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\include -IC:\\Users\\aniketb\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\theano\\gof -o C:\\Users\\aniketb\\AppData\\Local\\Theano\\compiledir_Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-3.5.2-64\\cuda_ndarray\\cuda_ndarray.pyd mod.cu -LC:\\Users\\aniketb\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\libs -LC:\\Users\\aniketb\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3 -lcublas -lpython35 -lcudart')
WARNING (theano.sandbox.cuda): CUDA is installed, but device gpu is not available  (error: cuda unavailable)
nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).
mod.cu

['nvcc', '-shared', '-O3', '-LC:\\Anaconda\\libs', '--compiler-bindir', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\bin', '-Xlinker', '/DEBUG', '-D HAVE_ROUND', '-m64', '-Xcompiler', '-DCUDA_NDARRAY_CUH=mc72d035fdf91890f3b36710688069b2e,-DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION,/Zi,/MD', '-IC:\\Users\\aniketb\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\theano\\sandbox\\cuda', '-IC:\\Users\\aniketb\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\core\\include', '-IC:\\Users\\aniketb\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\include', '-IC:\\Users\\aniketb\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\theano\\gof', '-o', 'C:\\Users\\aniketb\\AppData\\Local\\Theano\\compiledir_Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1-Intel64_Family_6_Model_58_Stepping_9_GenuineIntel-3.5.2-64\\cuda_ndarray\\cuda_ndarray.pyd', 'mod.cu', '-LC:\\Users\\aniketb\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3\\libs', '-LC:\\Users\\aniketb\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\Anaconda3', '-lcublas', '-lpython35', '-lcudart']

runfile('C:/Python27/test.py', wdir='C:/Python27')
[Elemwise{exp,no_inplace}(<TensorType(float32, vector)>)]
Looping 1000 times took 12.502791 seconds
Result is [ 1.23178029  1.61879337  1.52278066 ...,  2.20771813  2.29967761
  1.62323284]
Used the cpu
```

Any idea ?

Comment: same background, similar error here: Failed to compile cuda_ndarray.cu: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 96: invalid start byte

Comment: @NikolasRieble: had the same error. Solved it as described here https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/3551 by adding "iso-8859-1" to decode_iter. Careful: this is an ugly hack.